# Total surface area

Tags: geometry

> [click here for image](https://ibb.co/wyRYqrz)

Could I please have confirmation this is the correct way to solve this question  using the given information?

Note: I could not directly upload the image since it was apparently too large.

Comment: You should use image only for the graph, and write the math formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the area of the base you need to find the area of the triangle with side lengths given by $12$. To find the height of such a triangle it appears as though you have done the correct thing by taking $x=\sqrt{12^2-6^2}=\sqrt{144-36}=\sqrt{108}$ giving you a base area of $\frac{1}{2}(12)\sqrt{108}=6\sqrt{108}$. For the other 3 sides we already know the height and base length is $12$ and it has a height of $9$ meaning that the area of one of the remaining faces is again $\frac{1}{2}(12)(9)=54$. To find the total area, we then need to sum up all the face's area giving us
$$A=54+54+54+6\sqrt{108}=162+36\sqrt{3}$$
Thus the answer that you have is correct!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Brain fart :')

Comment: You can still simplify the square root, cause 108=36*3.